# How to insert numeric variable into replaceWith (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, dom, replacewith

Here is the problem...

I have created an "i" variable as a counter and set it to 0.
I took a variable containing a DOM element, and wished to rplace the value of it by the number into "i". But as the value of the DOM element is a character and I try to insert a numeric value, I've got an error...

Any idea how to place the value of "i" replacing my element?

My code :

```js
compte = document.getElementById("compteurClics");
i = 0;
var boutonElts = document.getElementById("clic");
boutonElts.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Un clique de plus!");
  i++;
});

compte.replaceWith(i);

stop = document.getElementById("desactiver");
stop.addEventListener("desactiver", function() {
  stop.removeEventListener("click");
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Compteur de clics</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="clic">Cliquez-moi !</button>
  <p>Vous avez cliqué <span id="compteurClics">0</span> fois</p>
  <button id="desactiver">Désactiver le comptage</button>

  <script src="../js/compteurClics.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: En anglais s'il vous plaît! <3

Comment: @Blacksilver It's (mostly) clear that Voodoobear wants the number to update when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want to do:

```
var compte = document.getElementById("compteurClics");
var i = 0;

var boutonElts = document.getElementById("clic");

function onClick() {
    console.log("Un clique de plus!");
    i++;
    compte.textContent = i;
}

boutonElts.addEventListener("click", onClick);

// compte.replaceWith(i);

var stop = document.getElementById("desactiver");

stop.addEventListener("click", function() {
    boutonElts.removeEventListener("click", onClick);
});
```

Comment: You got it! It works now! I hope I didn't bother, I'm just starting to learn and I wonder if it was as frustrating and hard at the begining for everybody, but to me, it is ^_^
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

[`replaceWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith) replaces the *entire* element with the number, which won't work a second time because the element doesn't exist any more. You can set the element's [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```js
compte = document.getElementById("compteurClics");
i = 0;
var boutonElts = document.getElementById("clic");
boutonElts.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Un clique de plus!");
  i++;
  compte.textContent = i;
});

stop = document.getElementById("desactiver");
stop.addEventListener("desactiver", function() {
  stop.removeEventListener("click");
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Compteur de clics</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="clic">Cliquez-moi !</button>
  <p>Vous avez cliqué <span id="compteurClics">0</span> fois</p>
  <button id="desactiver">Désactiver le comptage</button>

  <script src="../js/compteurClics.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You have to do this in the `"click"` event handler because number primitives in JavaScript aren't mutable, and the string outputted by the `toString` function wouldn't update itself anyway, especially not when added to the DOM.

Comment: Doesn't work, since it does not replace the "0" of "compteurClics".

Comment: @Voodoobear It works on my computer. Are you clicking the button?

Comment: The snippet works, `compte.textContent = i;` DOES replace the intial `0` with the value of `i`.

Comment: My mistake, i forgot a damn comma! Thanks =)
This is my first code with Javascript, sorry for stupid mistakes!

Comment: @Voodoobear You were using a function that would replace the entire element, instead of just its content (so it would only work once because the element wouldn't exist any more afterwards). That and only ending up running the function once were your two mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use `innerHTML` property inside event listener function?

```js
compte = document.getElementById("compteurClics");
i = 0;
var boutonElts = document.getElementById("clic");
boutonElts.addEventListener("click", function() {
 console.log("Un clique de plus!");

    compte.innerHTML = ++i;
});


stop = document.getElementById("desactiver");
stop.addEventListener("desactiver", function() {
 stop.removeEventListener("click");
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Compteur de clics</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="clic">Cliquez-moi !</button>
    <p>Vous avez cliqué <span id="compteurClics">0</span> fois</p>
    <button id="desactiver">Désactiver le comptage</button>

    <script src="../js/compteurClics.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```